# How to Selenium Load Chrome Extensions in a Specific Location

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue with Selenium (chrome+python 3.9) when loading extensions. I have set the user-data-dir to a specific location, but additionally loaded extensions from CRX are still loaded into to the localappdata.

Is there a way to force the extensions to load into another directory that isn't the randomly generated name in the appdata folder?

Comment: Unpack the extensions and specify the directories instead of crx.

Comment: I didn't think of this approach. Works for me, thanks a bunch!